# Grouping and auto increment based on columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

i have a pandas frame that looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way to add the numbers in the last column without having to iterate through the data frame?

I was playing with the results of [Grouping and auto incrementing group id in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28823979/grouping-and-auto-incrementing-group-id-in-pandaspost) but haven't made it work for my purposes

Here is the code to produce the dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
columns = ['Product','SubProd', 'NeedThis']
Index=['4/20/2012','4/27/2012','5/4/2012','5/11/2012','5/18/2012','4/20/2012',
'4/27/2012','5/4/2012','5/11/2012','5/18/2012','5/25/2012','10/31/2014','11/7/2014',
'11/14/2014','11/21/2014','11/28/2014']
datas = {'Product' : ['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B'],
      'SubProd' : ['BL','BL','BL','BL','BL','lk','lk','lk','lk','lk','lk','po','po','po','po','po']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=datas, index=Index)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
           Product SubProd
4/20/2012        A      BL
4/27/2012        A      BL
5/4/2012         A      BL
5/11/2012        A      BL
5/18/2012        A      BL
4/20/2012        A      lk
4/27/2012        A      lk
5/4/2012         A      lk
5/11/2012        A      lk
5/18/2012        A      lk
5/25/2012        A      lk
10/31/2014       B      po
11/7/2014        B      po
11/14/2014       B      po
11/21/2014       B      po
11/28/2014       B      po
```

Thanks

Comment: Sorry are you wanting `df.groupby('SubProd').rank(method='dense') + 1`?

Comment: Unfortunately this produces a table with the dates and Product =2

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
In [10]: df['counter'] = df.groupby(['Product','SubProd']).cumcount()+1

In [11]: df
Out[11]: 
           Product SubProd  counter
4/20/2012        A      BL        1
4/27/2012        A      BL        2
5/4/2012         A      BL        3
5/11/2012        A      BL        4
5/18/2012        A      BL        5
4/20/2012        A      lk        1
4/27/2012        A      lk        2
5/4/2012         A      lk        3
5/11/2012        A      lk        4
5/18/2012        A      lk        5
5/25/2012        A      lk        6
10/31/2014       B      po        1
11/7/2014        B      po        2
11/14/2014       B      po        3
11/21/2014       B      po        4
11/28/2014       B      po        5
```